# compare different combinations of a string

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary with key value pairs something like below

```
dict("A-B-C", "This is abc");
dict("X-Y-Z", "This is xyz");
so on
```

now when I receive an input say something like "B-A-C" the system should intelligent to know its "A-B-C" or if its "Z-Y-X" should map to "X-Y-Z", one way is to put all the combinations into the dictionary such that say dict("B-A-C", "A-B-C") but this may lead to more maintainability thing, just thinking if there is anything from .NET framework can address this issue more easily.

Is there an easy way to compare a string like below

```
A string either A-B or B-A is equal to A-B

A string either A-B-C or B-C-A or A-C-B or C-A-B or C-B-A equals to A-B-C

likewise a different combinations of A-B-C-D should equals to A-B-C-D

so as A-B-C-D-E

so on
```

A B C D E in the above example are a two letter non numeric word. something like 
Su-Ma-Ju-Ve

**UPDATE**
For now I solved this with below code which returns the string tokens in the order which is recognized in the dictionary I maintain, not sure if its the best way but is solving the problem for now

```
string sortPls(string pls)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> dctPls = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dctPls["Su"] = 1;
    dctPls["Mo"] = 2;
    dctPls["Ju"] = 3;
    dctPls["Me"] = 4;
    dctPls["Ve"] = 5;
    dctPls["Ma"] = 6;
    dctPls["Sa"] = 7;
    string[] arrPls = pls.Split('-');
    int j = 0;
    string sortPls = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrPls.Length; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < arrPls.Length; j++)
        {
            if (dctPls[arrPls[j]] < dctPls[arrPls[i]])
            {
                string tmp = arrPls[i];
                arrPls[i] = arrPls[j];
                arrPls[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < arrPls.Length; k++)
        sortPls += arrPls[k] + "-";
    return sortPls.Remove(sortPls.Length - 1) ;
}
```

Comment: What about "ABBA" equal to "AB"?

Comment: The simple answer is "yes", but what have you tried? Also, can you have repeated letters in the string (i.e. is "A-B-B" equal to "B-A-B"). Are repeats important (i.e. is "A-B-B" equal to "B-A")? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: No there is no repeated letters, only the combinations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If looking for set equality, then `HashSet<T>` gives you the tools.

```
"ABBA".ToHashSet().SetEquals("BA")
```

Otherwise for an "anagram" type comparison, order the characters and compare sequences:

```
"CDAB".OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual("DCBA".OrderBy(x=>x))
```

Comment: Thanks, is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This has answered to my question but still not solving the problem, as A B C D are going to be dynamic values don't know which one to pass in to .SequenceEqual("????").OrderBy(x=>x)), this solution works if only I know its A B C D or W X Y Z

Comment: @Naga This is why variables, parameters and arguments exist. Write a function that takes a string and returns a bool and use the string parameter instead of "ABCD"

Comment: that way i have to check all combinations for each combination of abc xyz abcd wxyz abcde vwxyz will be more

Comment: for now i solved it by sort function, code updated in my question, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into individual letters, add the letters to a Set, and compare the sets using their Equals methods

Comment: What is a Set in C#?

Comment: Yes, I thought about this solution but little curious to know if there is any other easy way to achieve same, as this piece of code runs in a loop

Comment: Set in c# is hashset

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    string check = "CADB";
    string equalTo = new string(check.ToCharArray().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(equalTo);
}
```

is just one way to do that.

Comment: `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` so here `ToCharArray()` is redundant.

Comment: @spender, I know that, but not having intellisense without ToCharArray() confuses people. And it would only save nanoseconds.

Comment: The only issue in my case is that there is '-' separators so if I give C-A-D-B equalTo returns ---ABCD instead what I want is A-B-C-D, could work this solution without separators, just thinking about it

Comment: @Naga, I didn't know you had - in string, then simply do a s.Replace("-","") first.

Comment: Sorry that my question must be misleading, A B C D is of 2 letter non numeric word in my code, not just A B C D

Comment: @Naga, sorry I don't understand. I thought those were strings like 'A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD' ...

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will be the fastest way to do it:

```
bool StringEquals(string string1, string string2)
{
    foreach (char ch in string1)
    {
        if (!string2.Contains(ch))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It might be the fastest but doesn't do what he wants. For example "ABA" would seem too be equal to "ABC" when it is not.

Comment: I could accept this answer as for now there are inputs in only combinations and not like ABA

Comment: @Cetin Basoz, there are no dublicate letters, so it does exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the characters in each string, any two strings that have the same characters will have their sorted version the same. Stick the results into a `Dictionary>, with the sorted version as the key.